# Don't want isc-dhcp to ever reallocate reserved ip even if hosts is down

Tags: linux, dhcp, configuration

I've allocated ip's to some systems through dhcp and then made entries in dhcpd.conf for reservation so that these ip's are not allocated to other macs. But when the system with reserved ip is offline and another client make dhcp request the reserved ip is alocated to it.
My dhcpd.conf is following.

```
ddns-update-style interim;
ignore client-updates;
subnet 10.10.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 10.10.10.2 10.10.10.20 ;
option routers                    10.10.10.1;
option subnet-mask                255.255.255.0;
option time-offset                -18000;
max-lease-time 10000000;
option domain-name "inclined";
option broadcast-address 10.10.10.255;
next-server 10.10.10.1;
host inc10 {
hardware ethernet 00:50:56:29:E8:F7 ;
fixed-address 10.10.10.2 ;
}
host inc12 {
hardware ethernet 00:0C:29:81:A5:C1 ;
fixed-address 10.10.10.3 ;
}
host inc23 {
hardware ethernet 00:0C:29:86:A6:72 ;
fixed-address 10.10.10.4 ;
}
host inc34 {
hardware ethernet 00:0C:29:92:17:E3 ;
fixed-address 10.10.10.5 ;
}
}
```

Suppose host inc34 is down and another new host requests an ip then 10.10.10.5 is allocated to it. I don't want dhcp to ever reallocate reserved ip to other hosts.
Any suggestions are much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer would be to put the IP's of the machines with static IP's outside the range allocated - ie fixed-addresses do not need to be in the "range" pool.

In your case the easiest solution might be to change the range to

> range 10.0.0.6 10.0.0.20;